# Making column hierarchies (as opposed to Index hierarchies) for a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

So this is something that so far seems like it's a lot more difficult to find out about than it should be.

Everything about hierarchies I've found has had to do with Index hierarchies, and much less so for column hierarchies.

I'm dealing with a scenario where the data for each individual row has to belong to only 1 person. As such, what I'm interested in is doing something like the following.

I'll illustrate this using a table where 3 people each took the same 3 tests (English, Chem, Math).
I'm trying to go about converting a table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'Mary', 1: 'Mary', 2: 'Mary', 3:'John',4:'John',5:'John',6:'Fred',7:'Fred',8:'Fred'}, 
                   'Test': {0: 'English', 1: 'Chem', 2: 'Math', 3:'English',4:'Chem',5:'Math',6:'English',7:'Chem',8:'Math'}, 
                   'Score': {0: '100', 1: '70', 2: '80', 3:'90',4:'100',5:'100',6:'80',7:'80',8:'90'},
                   'Grade': {0: 'A', 1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3:'A',4:'A',5:'A',6:'B',7:'B',8:'A'}})

df
```

**Output:**

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/16cc8ae43103fcaf7d96a82bec7dbb31.png]

Into this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/56c93974712d34409ebffc8639d1c0f2.png]

The major distinction of this from an ordinary pivot is that it outputs a multi-column table - which is why I'm lost as to where to even start.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), instead post as text please

Comment: Added sample code that generates the first table to go along with it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Test', values=['Score', 'Grade'])` I don't see why you think this isn't an ordinary pivot, you can get a MultiIndex from a `pivot` (add on `.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)` if you need the levels to be organized as you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.set_index(['Name','Test']).unstack().swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
 Test  Chem       English        Math      
      Grade Score   Grade Score Grade Score
Name                                      
Fred     B    80       B    80     A    90
John     A   100       A    90     A   100
Mary     C    70       A   100     B    80
```

Per comments if you want to use the same ordering for other columns, you can use:

```
m=df.set_index(['Name','Test'])
(m.unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
      .sort_index(axis=1).reindex(columns=m.columns,level=1))
```

---

```
 Test  Chem       English        Math      
       Score Grade   Score Grade Score Grade
Name                                      
Fred    80     B      80     B    90     A
John   100     A      90     A   100     A
Mary    70     C     100     A    80     B
```

Comment: Yep, this is one of the moments on stack overflow where I go "how did he even know that..."!! Thanks so much, only question left puzzling me are why that worked, and whether it's readily possible to swap around the 'Grade' and 'Score' columns - not that it's a big issue.